# Fazer dois updates ao mesmo tempo

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, sql-update

Tenho uma tabela com alguns registros, quero alterar duas linhas dessa tabela ao mesmo tempo

atualmente estou fazendo isso:

```
include("conexao.php");

$tabela1 = "endereco";

$endereco_id= "75";
$antigo_endereco_id= "73";

$res = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE $tabela1 SET $tabela1.endereco_favorito = 0
WHERE $tabela1.endereco_id = :antigo_endereco_id");
$res->bindParam(':antigo_endereco_id',$antigo_endereco_id);
$res->execute();

$res = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE $tabela1 SET $tabela1.endereco_favorito = 1
WHERE $tabela1.endereco_id = :endereco_id");
$res->bindParam(':endereco_id',$endereco_id);
$res->execute();
```

Porém queria algum jeito de fazer os dois updates ao mesmo tempo, fazer um depois o outro tá causando problemas que as vezes apenas um funciona e buga o banco de dados

Comment: Já pensou em executá-los dentro de uma transação?

Comment: Poderia me dar mais informações sobre isso ? Sou novo na área de banco de dados :)

Comment: Veja: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-acid.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema foi resolvido usando **transactions**
[ACID banco de dados](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-acid.html)

Primeiro habilite as exceções na instância do PDO:

```
$this->pdo = new PDO($this->db_host,$this->usuario,$this->senha,array(
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false));
```

Essas são as linhas necessárias a adicionar:

```
PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
```

Depois coloque as requisições necessárias dentro desse bloco:

```
try {
    $this->pdo->beginTransaction();

    $db->query('query 1'); //Exemplos
    $db->query('query 2');
    $db->query('query 3');

    $this->pdo->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $this->pdo->rollback();
}
```

As alterações só serão salvas caso todas as operações forem bem sucedidas!

Answer (score 0):

faz uma inserção por vez, usa 
`last insert id` 
para PDO 
`mysql_insert_id`
para MYSQLI

Comment: Mas no meu caso eu estava querendo fazer UPDATE, gostaria de fazer ambos de uma vez para não haver chance de modificar apenas uma coisa e a outra dar errado!